# How to copy files over Network to LocalDrive in Java

Tags: java

I need a sample code that copies files over Network  to Local File System in Java.
How this is done in Java?

Comment: Are you going to write your own server too? Or are you copying over, say, FTP or something?

Comment: to add to aioobe's point, are you looking to copy files from a "mapped" network drive, a file server listening on a remote socket and port?

Answer (score 0):

here is code that copies files in the local file system

```
 File fromfile = new File("file");
    File tofile = new File("../copiedfile");
    tofile.createNewFile();
    FileInputStream from = new FileInputStream(fromfile);
    FileOutputStream to = new FileOutputStream(tofile);
    byte [] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int bytesread;
    while ((bytesread = from.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        to.write(buffer, 0, bytesread);
    }
```

I think, if you want to copy files over network you should send buffer using `ObjectOutput` and sockets